# How to get typeof variable in AST?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jscodeshift

How to get what is the `typeof` of variable in AST?

```
const code = `const foo = () => {
  const baz = this;
}`;
```

I want to find the variables that are typeof `globalThis`. (for example `baz` is `typeof globalThis`)

Any idea how to do that?

transform code:

```
module.exports = (fileInfo, api, options) => {
  
  const j = api.jscodeshift;
  const root = j(fileInfo.source);
  
  root.find(j.Identifier)
   .forEach(x => {
    if (x.value.name === 'baz') {
        console.log({ x });
        // type: typeof globalThis??
    }
    
  });
  
  return root.toSource();
}
```

[astexplorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/541ba10e75228eeb83ccf95589b0bd76/bd1083ebd0b54674b994af1f809cef51a2588855)

Comment: Not really an answer, but ast of JS does not have type info, that is a runtime thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are looking in wrong AST viewer.

For TS, you can use [TS AST viewer](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/)
Or, you can use directly TS compiler API, which you can find [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API)

Comment: make sense. I'll take a look.